# Как правильно: 256 битов или 256 бит?

Tags: орфография, склонение

Как правильно написать единицы измерения количества информации:
*256 **битов*** или *256 **бит***?

Answer (score 3):

Грамота.ру объясняет, что в род.п. множ. числа названия мер и единиц измерения в сочетании с цифрами пишутся с нулевым окончанием: 220 вольт, 1000 ватт, 5 ампер, 500 гигабайт, 256 бит. Если же такие названия употребляются вне "измерительного" контекста (иначе говоря, форма родительного падежа не является счетной), то используется окончание -ов: жить без избыточных килограммов, не хватает гигабайтов, битов.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=plural

Comment: Людмила, это очень поверхностное объяснение. "50 **метр**"?
"Для проведения теста памяти в единицы были установлены 256 **бит**"?
И самое главное: подлежит ли этот список расширительному толкованию?

Comment: Автора интересовали только биты, с метрами всё понятно. Если нужно подробно, то здесь:  http://licey.net/russian/culture/2_2_3  Формы с -ов воспринимаются как более официальные.  Не в счётной форме  эти существительное обязательно имеют окончание -ов.
Окончание -ов является обязательным в любом контексте у следующих существительных:
акр (10 акров), гектар (10 гектаров), дюйм (5 дюймов), литр (10 литров), метр (5 метров), километр (5 километров), миллиметр (10 миллиметров), сантиметр (10 сантиметров), пуд (10 пудов), фунт (10 фунтов), фут (5 футов), ярд (5 ярдов).

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. )))
Реально используются оба варианта, в профессиональной речи чаще используется более короткий, т.н. счетная форма по образцу 220 вольт или 50 ватт. 
Лично мне она кажется здесь вполне уместной, но есть оппоненты, утверждающие, что список единиц измерений, для которых эта форма нормативна, не подлежит расширению.

Answer (score 1):

*Из входной последовательности выбирается очередной блок длиной **256 бит*** (А. Петров. Компьютерная безопасность).

В орфографическом словаре:
[**бит**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82&all=x), -а; *р. мн.* **-ов**, *счётн. ф.* **бит** (единица количества информации).

Если слово "бит" используется в родительном падеже множественного числа вместе с числительным, то употребляется так называемая счетная форма — **бит**.

*Между тем воспринимать и перерабатывать на уровне понимания мы можем не более **50 бит** информации одновременно* (О. Д. Халтагарова).

*...эти вундеркинды стопроцентно используют способность человеческого мозга перерабатывать в секунду до **четырех миллиардов бит** информации* (Э. Тополь).

Без конкретного обозначения количества (то есть без числительного) — **битов**:
показатели степени равны номерам битов;
аналогично можно обнулить несколько битов;
поток битов;
сколько битов содержится в сообщении?